# rank$(A)=$rank$(A|b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I need to prove,A system of Linear equations  $Ax=b$ is consistent iff rank$A=$rank$(A|b)$.where $A|b$ is the augmented matrix.

My try:
Let $A $ be $m×n $matrix and $A $ has rank $r $.
Let the given system is consistent.Then by Gaussian elimination we transform $A|b $to $A'|b'$, the row reduced echelon form. Clearly rank$A$ = rankA$'$ and rank$A|b$ = rank$A'|b'$. If possible let rank$A <$ rank$A|b $, ie. rank $A'<$ rank$A'|b'$. Then there exists a row of $A'|b $ has nonzero 1 at the last column. Again if we add this row with a non-zero row of $A'$, I shall find a non-consistent system which is a contradiction. (It's trivial to note that rank$A>$ rank$A|b $ can't happen. )

Conversely, let rank $A = $rank $A|b$ and the system is inconsistent. By suitable gaussian elimination I can obtain an equation that gives two values simultaneously. So then using row reduced echelon form operation, I see rank of $A $ and $A|b $ are different. Which is also a contradiction.
Am I correct? 
Any other way to prove it will also help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system is consistent, there is a solution $x$ such that $Ax = b$. The components of $x$ give a linear combination of $A$'s columns to eliminate $b$ in the matrix $(A|b)$, hence $\text{rank}(A|b) = \text{rank}(A|0) = \text{rank}(A)$.

Conversely, if $\text{rank}(A|b) = \text{rank}(A)$, it means that the columns of $A$ generate the same subspace as the columns of $(A|b)$. As $b$ belongs to this subspace, there is a linear combination of $A$'s columns that is equal to $b$, but this means exactly that the system $A x=b$ has a solution.

Comment: Thanks...I have made my problem too complicated,Is that correct what I have done?please justify

Comment: Yes I think your proof is correct. You could perhaps transform it by interpreting the gaussian elimination as a product with a convenient matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n},b \in K^{m}$$ are columns of $(A, b),$

then $$x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n}$$ are solution of $ U$ then and only then, if

$$x_{1}\alpha_{1}+x_{2}\alpha_{2}+...+x_{n}\alpha_{n} = b.$$

Hence

$U$ has solution $\leftrightarrow  b \in lin(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},..., \alpha_{n}) \leftrightarrow lin(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},..., \alpha_{n}) = lin(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n}, b)\leftrightarrow  dim(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n})= dim(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{n}, b)\leftrightarrow r(A)= r(A, b).$